# Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to Simple Http Server seems doesn't work properly

Tags: python, ajax, python-2.7, server, simplehttpserver

I just want to allow make ajax request to any origin using Python SimpleHttpServer:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

class MyHTTPRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)



httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyHTTPRequestHandler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Still the error remains:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://abcd.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I launch it by `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a header set by the *source* of the content you’re trying to load. Allowing the requesting page to set the header would make the same-origin policy pointless.

Comment: @minitech, I don't understand that, say it simpler.

Comment: @minitech, most importantly how to fix it.

Comment: If you don’t own `abcd.com`, this is impossible to fix, for security reasons.